# Taking back an old computer to live, SCREEN seems half dead, Vertical Lines and few colours

Tags: laptop, display

Just trying to take an old computer back to live, but screen seems half dead

Image attached: vertical lines (like second pixel?), even in bios, on windows colours seems to be like a 1995 old 4 colours game,

with external monitor, everything right

Should be screen?, wires?,
and what can be possible solution ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziLbu.jpg)

Comment: The dv9000 was prone to motherboard failure. It’s almost a surprise it still works at all. HP sold tens of thousands of dv2000, dv6000 and dv9000 series laptops. Literally, probably the worst laptop’s ever made. It resulted in a class action lawsuit. It could be the screen, the cable or very likely a motherboard based on its history. You’re going down a dark road with that system full of “refurbished” motherboards on eBay that have been baked in people’s ovens and other non-sense.

Comment: nice (looking) paperweight I have then ... , Strange behaviour, on video, dark colours/images (bellow 40% clarity) seems right, as a light comes, seems like a psychedelic effect.  Like you uglily play with the curves tools in photoshop.